# what is the name of this encryption method called used

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

i once watched a tutorial on youtube on how to encrypt passwords using different methods like sha1,crypt,md5 and hash most people say its easy to decrypt md5 passwords once the hacker knows your method you used for encryption,my question is there any written document on algorithm on how to encrypt passwords like that?? i tried to do this code below after i watched a tutorial and it worked perfectly

```
 $password =trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));
     $hash_password = md5($password);
     $hash_password1 = sha1($hash_password);
     $hash_password2 = crypt($hash_password1,"st");
     $hash_password3 = hash("sha512",$hash_password2);
```

does this algorithm have a name??i want to know more about it any ideas or what the algorithm is called please share with me,im just a newbie and i really want to know more about this,thanks in advance

Comment: It's called, chaining a bunch of hashing algorithms because the programmer naively thinks it will make their system more secure, which is [not a safe assumption](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/18089/11952), at the cost of an increase in complexity and drop in efficiency.

Comment: @nickb so its just a way programmers found to encrypt data there is no special algorithm about it right??

Comment: Right, no special algorithm, no special name, nothing really worth implementing or further investigating.

Comment: can potentially decrease security

Comment: YouTube tutorials may not be the best place to learn cryptography.

Comment: Your code is lacking a salt, which is essential for password hashing. Your hashing is pretty weird too. Just use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat , it's easy to use and pretty good.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What sorts of attacks you want to prevent?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Comment: Yes, but what you are trying to do does not increase security. However, the use of salt does.